# best way to combine guava eventbus and AWT Event thread handling

Tags: java, awt, guava

When you have a asynchronous event bus, and fire events, lets say within the model which get catched in the UI you have probably the following problem:

The registered handler gets executed in a worker thread, but all UI swing changes need to be executed within the AWT event thread.
This means you need to envelope all your handler clode in `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`.

This looks like a lot of boiler plate code.
I wonder if there is a smarter solution for that problem.

What about an extension to the guava event bus that marks a handler for execution within a special thread? This could be marked with a annotion e.g. `@ExecuteWithinEDT`:

```
class EventBusChangeRecorder {
  @Subscribe @ExecuteWithinEDT void recordCustomerChange(ChangeEvent e) {
    recordChange(e.getChange());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The handlers registered with an async event bus are executed on whatever thread the provided `Executor` chooses to run them on, not necessarily a worker thread.

What I've done is created an implementation of `Executor` that runs stuff on the event queue thread. It's pretty simple:

```
public class EventQueueExecutor implements Executor {
  @Override public void execute(Runnable command) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(command);
  }
}
```

You can then just create your `EventBus` with that:

```
EventBus eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(new EventQueueExecutor());
```

Then all handlers will be executed on the event queue thread.

**Edit:**

An example of forwarding events:

```
public class EventForwarder {
  private final EventBus uiEventBus;

  public EventForwarder(EventBus uiEventBus) {
    this.uiEventBus = uiEventBus;
  }

  // forward all events
  @Subscribe
  public void forwardEvent(Object event) {
    uiEventBus.post(event);
  }

  // or if you only want a specific type of event forwarded
  @Subscribe
  public void forwardEvent(UiEvent event) {
    uiEventBus.post(event);
  }
}
```

Just subscribe that to your main event bus and post all events to the main event bus, but subscribe all UI components to the UI event bus.

Comment: Your solution is nice, but it gives another problem: now ALL events are dispatched within AWT. In a real world application I would probably want some subscribers to be dispatched within AWT (the GUI part) whereas other subsribers (from the model or another module) should be NOT dispatched within AWT. Otherwise the whole asyncrhonous event bus would not make much sense.

Comment: @langm: One option is to have multiple `EventBus`es... one that calls handlers on the event queue and one that doesn't. Handlers that want to be called on the event queue subscribe to that event bus. You can then have a handler or handlers that subscribe to the OTHER event bus and handle certain types of events by posting them to the event queue bus.

Comment: that would probably a solution. but would mean, I would have to subscribe twice: once the UI, once the UI bus by the other bus.... a nice feature would be a forwarding function to just forward all events globally to another bus. does this make sense?

Comment: @langm: You can easily forward all events to another bus. Remember that event dispatching is done by type: if an event handler subscribes to Object events, it will receive all events. So you could forward all events from one bus to another with a single subscriber that way. Also, if you only want specific types of events to go the UI, you could have all of those events implement a tagging interface and only forward events of that interface type to the UI.

Comment: @ColinD: Beware that since `EventForwarder` is subscribed to all events, there are no longer any `DeadEvents`.

Comment: @DrewS: If you're using a second `EventBus` to dispatch UI events, there will be `DeadEvent`s on that bus for unhandled events.

Comment: @ColinD: Ah, Indeed. The code registering the `DeadEvent` listener now has to be aware of the whole multiple-event-buses situation, but that's ok (for my situation).  I'll also add another `EventBus` and Forwarder to handle the `DeadEvent` off of the EDT, but that's ok too.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an EventBus that dispatches only on the AWT thread:

```
EventBus mybus = new AsyncEventBus("awt",
    new Executor() {
        public void execute (Runnable cmd) {
            if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                cmd.run();
            } else {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(cmd);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, the same as with my other comment to the above post: all events are now dispatched in AWT. What I wanted is a way so that each individual subscriber could decide to dispatch in AWT or not. Otherwise a asynchonous event bus would make no real sense in a real world app