# Java Inheritance - Trying to make generic method to get a bus from Guava EventBus library

Tags: java, inheritance

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522073/2240409) I'm trying to create a library that creates an `EventBus` or an `AsyncEventBus` from Guava EventBus Library.

So I tried to create a class that extends Guava's `AsyncEventBusClass`, so I created `RetroAsyncEventBus` as follows:

```
public class RetroAsyncEventBus extends AsyncEventBus{

    private AsyncEventBus asyncEventBus;

    public RetroAsyncEventBus(Executor executor) {
        super(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public void register(Object object) {
        super.register(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregister(Object object) {
        super.unregister(object);
    }
}
```

Firstly here I don't understand why I've to `Override` `register` and `unregister`, from what I understand from inheritance, I should be able to access this super methods thru RetroAsyncEventBus object, I mean I should be able to do this:

```
RetroAsyncEventBus retroAsyncEventBus = new RetroAsyncEventBus(executor);
retroAsyncEventBus.register(this);
```

but my IDE (netbeans) says I can't with compile error: `cannot find symbol` at `retroAsyncEventBus.register(this);`. So I had to `Override` them, I can live with that.

Then I've my RetroBus class where I create and initialize the bus I want, in a `singleton` approach. Like this:

```
public class RetroBus {

    private final EventBus bus;
    private final AsyncEventBus asyncEventBusMainThread;
    private final AsyncEventBus asyncEventBus;
    private static RetroBus instance;

    private RetroBus(){
        bus = new EventBus();
        asyncEventBusMainThread = new AsyncEventBus(new EventQueueExecutor());
        asyncEventBus = new AsyncEventBus(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }

    public synchronized static EventBus getDefaultBus()
    {
        if (instance == null) 
        {
            instance = new RetroBus();
            return instance.getDefaultEventBus();
        }
        return instance.getDefaultEventBus();
    }

    public synchronized static AsyncEventBus getAsyncBus()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new RetroBus();
            return instance.getAsyncEventBus();
        }
        return instance.getAsyncEventBus();
    }

    public synchronized static AsyncEventBus getAsyncBusToMainThread()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new RetroBus();
            return instance.getAsyncEventBusMainThread();
        }
        return instance.getAsyncEventBusMainThread();
    }

    private EventBus getDefaultEventBus() {
        return this.bus;
    }

    private AsyncEventBus getAsyncEventBus() {
        return this.asyncEventBus;
    }

    private AsyncEventBus getAsyncEventBusMainThread() {
        return this.asyncEventBusMainThread;
    }
}
```

Now my library compiles just fine. On my project to test I import my library and then I try to do this:

```
public class TestClass {

    private RetroAsyncEventBus retroAsyncEventBus;

        public TestClass() {

            retroAsyncEventBus =  (RetroAsyncEventBus) RetroBus.getAsyncBusToMainThread();
            retroAsyncEventBus.register(this);
        }
}
```

And here's where my real problems kick in. First it is forcing me to cast `RetroBus.getAsyncBusToMainThread();` and I don't get why I'm forced to cast it when `RetroAsyncEventBus` `extends` `AsyncEventBus` so they should be same type, am I right?

Then if I cast it, like I did, I get this compile error: `the type of getAsyncBusToMainThread(); is erroneous.`

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have to cast is because your method is returned `AsyncEventBus` not `RetroAsyncEventBus`. That means the program has to work with any possible `AsyncEventBus` objects the method returns.

Change the return type and you will no longer need the cast.